# Assigning methods to class attributes

Tags: python, oop

I have the following piece of code and i'm trying it to write it in a class using OOP style. Ultimately the desired output will be for the `full_results` list to be returned.

```
import datetime
def generate_dates():
    start_date = datetime.date(2020, 8, 24)
    end_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    diff = (end_date - start_date).days
    start_dates = []
    end_dates = []

    i = 0
    while i < diff:
        a_date = (start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).isoformat()
        b_date = (start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 10)).isoformat()
        start_dates.append(a_date)
        end_dates.append(b_date)
        i += 10


    return start_dates, end_dates

dates = generate_dates()
start_dates = dates[0]
end_dates = dates[1]


def get_report(start_date, end_date):
    pass


def get_data():
    full_results = []
    for i, row in enumerate(start_dates):
        z = get_report(row, end_dates[i])
        full_results.append(z)
    return full_results
```

Here's my attempt to write the same code in OOP. I'm new to this and i don't know how to assign a function to a variable as i have done above.

```
class GA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dates = None
        self.start_dates = None
        self.end_dates = None

    def generate_dates(self):
        start_date = datetime.date(2020, 8, 24)
        end_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
        diff = (end_date - start_date).days
        start_dates = []
        end_dates = []

        i = 0
        while i < diff:
            a_date = (start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).isoformat()
            b_date = (start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 10)).isoformat()
            start_dates.append(a_date)
            end_dates.append(b_date)
            i += 10
        return start_dates, end_dates

    dates = generate_dates()
    start_dates = dates[0]
    end_dates = dates[1]

    def get_report(self, start_date, end_date):
        pass

    def get_data(self):
        full_results = []
        for i, row in enumerate(self.start_dates):
            z = self.get_report(row, self.end_dates[i])
            full_results.append(z)
        return full_results
```

I have tried to refer to the now attributes using the `self` but it did not work either. Specifically i'm getting the error `TypeError: generate_dates() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`. I think there are many mistakes still, but this is the first error that i'm getting, so any help will be much appreciated.
p.s. Also if there's a better way to structure/write this, please do let me know.

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime
class GA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dates = None
        self.start_dates = None
        self.end_dates = None

    def generate_dates(self):
        start_date = datetime.date(2020, 8, 24)
        end_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
        diff = (end_date - start_date).days
        start_dates = []
        end_dates = []

        i = 0
        while i < diff:
            a_date = (start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).isoformat()
            b_date = (start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 10)).isoformat()
            start_dates.append(a_date)
            end_dates.append(b_date)
            i += 10
        return start_dates, end_dates

    def get_your_function_name(self):
        self.dates = self.generate_dates()
        self.start_dates = self.dates[0]
        self.end_dates = self.dates[1]
        return [ self.dates , self.start_dates , self.end_dates ]

    def get_report(self, start_date, end_date):
        pass

    def get_data(self):
        full_results = []
        for i, row in enumerate(self.start_dates):
            z = self.get_report(row, self.end_dates[i])
            full_results.append(z)
        return full_results


GA().generate_dates()
print(GA().get_your_function_name())
```

Comment: I dont really get your question but i hope this solves it

Comment: What is the purpose of `get_your_function_name`?

Comment: basically why do you want to assign that function in a variable even if you want to you could use self.variable way

Comment: Hi i've tried that as     self.dates = generate_dates()
    self.start_dates = dates[0]
    self.end_dates = dates[1] and didn't work. Can you provide me an example please?